# How can i call function chaining like without the use of the constructor(new) keyword?

Tags: javascript

i don't know how to call something like: let r = fun().func1(2).func2(2), without the use of new keyword. I know it via new keyword, something like let r = new fun().func1(2), but can I implement it with the syntax above.

Comment: What are the functions, which you are using?

Comment: Try using the concept of closures.

Comment: For chaining like that, you're going to _need_ some kind of factory/initializer/class. Whether you use a `new MyClass()` or a factory, it all boils down to the same kind of logic... Why don't you want that?

Answer (score 1):

Each function could return an object containing a function:

```js
function fun() {
  return {func1(num1) {
    return {func2(num2) { 
      return num1 * num2;
    }}
  }}
}

let r = fun().func1(2).func2(2);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: This isn't the same as the `new` case the OP describes, though. Here, each function has it's own distinct scope / parent.

Comment: @Cerbrus  Couldn't this be what the OP is actually wanting?.  He doesn't specifically say it's needs to be a class / aka factory.  In fact he even says -> `function chaining like`..

Answer (score 1):

You could build a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) by returning an object with the function, you need. To get a result, you need to specify a function which returns a value instead of an object, or implement a `toString` or `valueOf` function.

```js
const
    fun = (result = 0) => {
        const functions = {
            add (value) {
                result += value;
                return functions;
            },
            multiply (value) {
                result *= value;
                return functions;
            },
            ans () {
                return result;
            }
        }

        return functions;
    };

console.log(fun().add(2).multiply(3).ans());
```

Comment: Nice and clean.  I wonder if it's also worth pointing out to the OP, if `fun()` is used a lot & has lots of methods,  doing this using a class and a factory function would be more beneficial.